# Running .sql files in postgres (structured programs)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

In oracle I could create .sql files and run them with a structure (like a stored procedure) with

```
begin

  declare

end;
```

I did some tests, because I need to run scripts to fix problems, not is necessary record it as a stored procedure/function on server, so like in Oracle, I want to run it once and check the result.

Not is possible run .sql files on postgres with CURSOR, declare, variables, etc.. , only directly on server with stored procedures/functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of Oracle's anonymous PL/SQL blocks are anonymous PL/pgSQL blocks in Postgres. These are started using the [`do`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement:

```
do
$$
declare 
  ....
begin
  .... 
end;
$$
```

Comment: Another question only...when I ran the .sql, the 'body' of script (between 'do' and 'end') will be printed on my log file, can I avoid it ? 
I called the script via psql -d database -U user -a -f filepath
Here an example of output: https://i.postimg.cc/hGtqcrx1/screenshot-493.png

Comment: @MCunha98: `psql --quiet`?

Comment: hmmm...I didn't know this option, I'll do tests, thank again